# How to confirm Android M Auto Backup is working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, backup, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to confirm that Auto Backups are working in debug build?

Following the [Auto Backup](http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html) documentation, I was hoping to witness SharedPreferences being restored on a reinstall with Android M device:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true">
```

I install and run the app to modify some preferences. I confirm that my changes are persisted to the `data` directory correctly:

```
 $ adb shell
 $ run-as my.app
 $ cat /data/data/my.app/shared_prefs/my.app_preferences.xml
```

They look great. Next, I make sure backup manager is enabled and force a backup:

```
 $ bmgr enabled 
 Backup Manager currently enabled
 $ bmgr run
 $ bmgr fullbackup my.app
 Performing full transport backup
```

Finally, I uninstall and reinstall my debug build. After the app starts, I re-examine the files in `/shared_prefs` (as well as the app settings) but the data was not restored.

I have also tried explicitly restoring the backup (no luck) with:

```
$ bmgr restore my.app
```